# Specify Generics in interface extends

Tags: java, generics

Should I specify the concrete type for generic types when extending an interface with another interface?

What I mean is, if I have an interface:

```
public interface Repo<T>{
      Collection<T> search(String params);
      T get(String id);
}
```

and then a whole bunch specific Repositories, like **ClientRepo**, **CustomerRepo**, etc... is it reasonable to specify the type **T** when extending this interface, e.g.:

```
public interface ClientRepo extends Repo<Client>{
}
public interface CustomerRepo extends Repo<Customer>{
}
```

where Client and Customer are just some classes.

Did anyone have a similar problem? I mean I could do:

```
public interface ClientRepo<T> extends Repo<T>{
}
```

**Addendum**:
Perhaps I should make my intent for having specific Repos (e.g. ClientRepo) more clear. There is another interface  called **RepoFactory** that returns appropriate Repo to the client, e.g.:

```
public interface RepoFactory{
      ClientRepo createClientRepo();
      CustomerRepo createCustomerRepo();
}
```

This factory is implemented by **implementors** which in turn, provide the appropriate implementations of the concrete Repos.

In fact from the above you could say that the interface **Repo<T>** is not used by the client of the api.

Confusing enough I hope!!! Sorry :(

Comment: Seems reasonable to me.  In the last case you'd have to specify the type when you create a new ClientRepo.

Comment: By the way, where is the difference between `Client` and `Customer`?

Comment: Those are just examples, but they are separate business objects, essentially pojos with different fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the solution I was looking for was simply to throw out all my specialized interfaces:

```
public interface RepoFactory{
    Repo<Client> createClientRepo();
    Repo<Customer> createCustomerRepo(); }
```

This way I get to both keep my static type-checking to enforce the api and also gain an additional flexibility for implementations of my Factory.

Answer (score 8):

I've found a lot more utility in doing

```
public interface SomeRepo<T> extends Repo<T>{
}
```

Than in extending interfaces via

```
public interface ClientRepo extends Repo<Client>{
}
public interface CustomerRepo extends Repo<Customer>{
}
```

That said, I've done both in the past, and will likely wind up doing both in the future.  If you detect too much duplicate code in the latter solution, I'd do my best to replace it with the former solution.

If you want any practical issues, it seems that compilers have a harder time realizing that `public interface ClientRepo extends Repo' can be compatible with Repo.  It doesn't happen too often (but when it does it takes a number of attempts to get the generics interfacing right).

Comment: Depends on whether you have methods that only apply to one of the models but not the other. If clients are people whereas customers are corporations, you could have a repo method that returns all clients whose birthday is today which would not make sense for customers.

Answer (score 4):

Well it depends if your extending interface/class could be generic, too. In your example I would assume that you want to do

```
public interface ClientRepo extends Repo<Client>{
}
```

Because with

```
public interface ClientRepo<T> extends Repo<T>{
}
```

You could do things like

```
ClientRepo<Customer>
```

which is probably not the desired behaviour.

Comment: That is true. I am wandering whether I need the Repo<T> interface at all, as I am not sure how much it contributes vs. makes things confusing.

Comment: I would drop the "sub-interface".  If you are going to develop two "ClientRepos" and must guarantee they share an interface, then an interface makes sense.  In this case, it looks like you really only have one class to implement, and you already have a broader "Repo" interface for that one.

Comment: Understood. If you extended interfaces don't add any methods you can use the Repo class directly, too.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of generic interfaces (and generics on the whole) is to have a single generic implementation. I.e, even though your interface might have multiple implementations, they should all handle every valid parameter class.

If you remove the parameter in a subsequent layer of interfaces, it kind of defeats the idea of having a generic interface in the first place. After all, you could simply do:

```
 public interface Repo {
      Collection search(String params);
      Object get(String id);
 }

 public interface ClientRepo {
      Collection<Client> search(String params);
      Client get(String id);
 }
```

Of course if you have external code that supports parametrised operations on any `Repo` implementation, having a generic interface could still be useful. But you can also argue that these operations should be part of the `Repo` interface.

All in all, it's workable and isn't hard to justify but it looks a bit awkward to me: just by looking at your example, it's difficult to figure out what your intent is, which is always a sign of warning.

Comment: There is no reason of not having a class implementing only `Repo<Client>` and not `Repo<Customer>` - the benefit of having a generic interface is that we can use it in other APIs which take this generic interface and not have a special implementation of this other APIs for every type of `Repo`.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann That's exactly what I'm saying: but shouldn't those other APIs be part of the `Repo` interface in the first place?

Comment: No, it could be in some utility class (like `java.util.Collections`), or simply some consumer of `Repo<T>` objects for any `T`.  (As an example, there are quite more implementations of `Comparator<String>` compared to generic implementations of `Comparator<T>` which work for every `T`.)

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann Yes, this is often the case when you're writing a library. When you're writing an application however, this kind of use is much less frequent.

Answer (score 0):

You [could](http://rcmohan.wordpress.com/2009/10/23/how-i-used-java-generics/) define types properly

```
interface BaseType { }
interface Client extends BaseType {}
```

Then, you could define

```
interface Repo<T extends BaseType> {
    Collection<T> search(String params);
    T get(String id);
}
interface ClientRepo extends Repo<Client> { }
```

And with implementation

```
ClientRepo c = new ClientRepo() {
    @Override
    public Collection<Client> search(String params) {// implementation here
    }
    @Override
    public Client get(String id) {// implementation here
    }
};
```

obtain a stricter type checking.

Comment: That is a nice addition, thanks. I've thought about this as well - but it still does not answer whether the generic Repo interface is at all useful, or can be left out all together.