# How to enforce types on another interface after implementing an interface

Tags: java, types

I want to create a custom Function which enforces the types.

```
public interface StringGroupFunction implements Function<String, String> {
}
```

This does not allowed. Only possibility I found was making `StringGroupFunction` a abstract class. Any other ideas ?

Comment: Interfaces dont ***implement*** anything in java, they ***extend***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specify Generics in interface extends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460569/specify-generics-in-interface-extends)

Comment: @Joe why the duplicate ? it would be correct with an _extends_, no ?

Comment: @AxelH Probably because in generics, you also use `extends` for type implementing interfaces. But that's not the same question for me.

Comment: @AxelH Best dupe I could find for how to define an interface that enforces the types of a generic interface, which seems to be the question here.

Comment: Seems to me @Joe that his problem is how to "implements" interface in an interface, the genericity is out of scope ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common misunderstanding: An interface does not implement another interface, it extends it, as it doesn't provide a body to the functions.

As said in the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/nogrow.html):

> If you want to add additional methods to an interface, you have several options. You could create a DoItPlus interface that extends DoIt:
>
> ```
> public interface DoItPlus extends DoIt {
>   boolean didItWork(int i, double x, String s);
> }
> ```

You can read more about interfaces in the [java specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.1.3):

> If an extends clause is provided, then the interface being declared extends each of the other named interfaces and therefore inherits the member types, methods, and constants of each of the other named interfaces.
>
> These other named interfaces are the direct superinterfaces of the interface being declared.
>
> Any class that implements the declared interface is also considered to implement all the interfaces that this interface extends.

Comment: You should add the [JLS about interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.1.3) as this hold more information that the guide

Comment: I was about to post the answer but since you already gave enough information here. There is no point to duplicate them.